# Understanding instruction branching

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture, mips, processor

I need help in understanding the solution from solution manual. The question is from the exercise 4.22.1 of chapter 4 in the book Computer Organization and Design by Patterson and Hannessey (4th edition). The question is about branching in instruction pipeline.

> **The question**
>     We assume that the following MIPS code is executed on a pipelined processor
>   with a 5-stage pipeline, full forwarding, and a predict-taken branch predictor.
>     Consider the instruction sequence:
>       `Label1: LW R2,0(R2)`
>       `BEQ R2,R0,Label ; Taken once, then not taken`
>       `OR R2,R2,R3`
>       `SW R2,0(R5)`
>     Draw the pipeline execution diagram for this code, assuming
>   there are no delay slots and that branches execute in the EX stage.

The solution given is as follows:

> **The solution**
>   [image]

**The doubt**
I dont understand why in 4th cycle `LW` have `***` (blue underlined). Cant we execute `ID` of `LW` in 4th cycle? Is it unsaid rule that if the branch-decision-making-stage (that is red underlined `EX` of `BEQ`) gets delayed (here due to data dependency on first `LW` for `R2`), then delay all the corresponding next stages in the following instructions?

Answer (score 1):

So, "bubbles" or stalls due to dependencies are inserted after the instruction decode of the instruction with the dependency (the BEQ). It seems you are comfortable with this. However, as a result, the rest of the pipeline (containing the second LW) in it is stalled as well.

Consider it like this: it's not possible to stall an instruction and *not* stall the instructions following it. That would require two instructions to be in the same pipeline stage at the same time: if LW was not also stalled, then the EX of the BEQ and the EX of the LW would occur on the same clock cycle: not possible!

Comment: ok I think there is something more that added to my confusion: 3rd instruction `LW` is fetched immediately after 2nd instruction `BEQ`. But that is not the case with `OR`. It is fetched far after when preceding `BEQ` is in `MEM` stage. Is the `LW` still fetched after 2nd `BEQ, before `OR`, but because prediction went wrong it was abandoned and `OR` is fetched? Something like this:[image](https://s19.postimg.org/4yxgb1x03/pip.png)

Comment: @Mahesha999 Yes, I believe that is correct.